# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I have given unique key to every item but it still shows Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
<FormControl className="registerInputs">
  <InputLabel htmlFor="name-multiple">Country</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={country}
    placeholder="Country"
    input={<Input id="name-multiple" />}
    onChange={(e) => selectCountryHandler(e.target.value)}
  >
    {!!countryArr?.length &&
      countryArr.map(({ label, value }) => (
        <MenuItem key={label} value={value}>
          {label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

Comment: Double check that you don't have duplicate `label` properties. If you do find another property on your object that is guaranteed to be unique (an `id`?). Don't resort to using `index` as key as it will likely lead to unwanted side effects down the road.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your code, you have allotted the label as a key. I wonder if there are more than one similar labels that are giving you an error. I would suggest you use

```js
countryArr.map(({ label, value }, id) => (
            <MenuItem key={id} value={value}>
              {label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))
```

Please try this and do tell me if it is working or not.

Comment: This will most likely produce an (ESLint) warning, that you shouldn't use the index as the key (which you shouldn't)

Comment: Actually, I have been using this quite often. That's why I suggested this. But I will do note down your advice and try to figure out something else.

Comment: The reason keys exist is that React needs a way to identify which components are the same between rerenders of their parents. So for example if you have some children in a parent component and the parent rerenders the state of those children will be lost if there are no keys (with keys React knows: those are the same components) - The thing about using the index is, that you can manipulate an array (which can lead to React thinking: hey those components have the same key, so they are the same - but in acutallity they aren't and have just the same index) (very rough explanation)